# Rendering of the html page not working

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am using Backbonejs framework. Under this framework, I have created an app.js which uses Backbonejs, requirejs, underscore and text.js
I would like to load a html page onto a div. The console shows that the html page is loaded but I am not able to see that particular page on the screen.

Below is the app.js

```js
define(function (require) {

    // "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery'),
        underscore = require('assets/js/underscore'),
        Backbone = require('assets/js/backbone'),
        tpl = require('text!Views/home.html'),

        template = _.template(tpl);

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function () {
            el: '#banner',
            this.$el.html(template());
            return this;    
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to load the home.html to the main screen(index.html). I have called this app.js in the index.html. The console shows the following XHR finished loading: GET "file:///D:/Project1/Views/home.html"
But my index.html page doesn't show this home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code.

1. Backbone View needs to be instantiated
2. el needs to be defined outside render function
3. render function needs to be called, either manually or from within an initialize function (which invokes on creating instance of the View)
4. Overall structure is not well-written but I am not correcting that as it is out of the scope of this question.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsv/c4dveax9/

```
var tpl = "<div>hello world</div>";
var template = _.template(tpl);
(function(){
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#banner',
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(template());
        }
    });
    var v = new View();
})();
```

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

To access template from a file using requireJs (since you are using it) you can do it as follows:

Template File:

```
<!-- pod.html -->
<h2><%= title %></h2>
<p><%= body %></p>
```

Accessing the template from your JS:

```
// view.js
define(["text!templates/pod.html"], function(pod) {
  var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(pod)
  });
});
```

Check this link for reference: http://kilon.org/blog/2012/11/3-tips-for-writing-better-backbone-views/

Comment: You could refer to this article - 2nd tip for templating best practices - http://kilon.org/blog/2012/11/3-tips-for-writing-better-backbone-views/.
Using dependency management utility is a good option if you wish to keep templates in different files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code works. I have another doubt. Is there a possibility to pass the tpl as a URL because I have a html page which I need to render. Here you have directly written the html code in the tpl variable whereas I need to pass an url.

Comment: Yes, you can. I just commented before you to give you the answer, click on that link. Please check the 2nd tip - 2nd point.